# NiFi ReplaceText Processor inserting Empty strings

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, data-cleaning, data-processing

I'm trying to convert Fixed width file text file to pipe delimited text file. I'm using NiFi's ReplaceText Processor for doing the same. These are my processor configurations

Replacement Strategy-Regex Replace

Evaluation Mode-Line-by-Line

Line-by-Line Evaluation Mode-All

Search Value- (.{1})(.{4})(.{16})(.{11})(.{14})(.{1})(.{8})(.{16})(.{9})(.{19})(.{5})(.{14})(.{4})(.{33})

replacement Value- ${'$1':trim()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$3':trim()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$4':trim()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$5':toDecimal()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$8':trim()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$9':trim():toNumber()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$10':trim()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$11':toNumber()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$12':toDecimal()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${'$13':trim()}${literal('|'):unescapeXml()}${header:substring(63,69)}

I'm trying to split record according to the column length's provided to me and trying to trim spaces and and parsing to different types. In this process I observe that randomly some column in output file are empty strings even though the records in fixed width file contains some data. I can't figure out why the expression evaluation is inserting zero length strings randomly in the file. When I'm trying to with small set of records(some 100 records) from original file it is working fine. My original file is having 12 million records in it.

Comment: edit your question and add example of input lines that fails, expected output and actual output.

Comment: btw, probably you have different line-endings for different lines